# VBA Excel: Inserting SUM function, but it always equals zero

Tags: vba, function, excel, sum

I'm cleaning up a file and I'm trying to SUM values together, but the sum always equals to zero. My code gives the correct range, and does the correct formatting... Just can't get the sum to show anything but 0.

```
Sub AddBlankRows()
'
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range
Dim fRow As Integer

Set oRng = Range("e2")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column
fRow = iRow

Do
'
  If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    iRow = iRow + 1
    Range("k" & iRow).Font.Bold = True
    Range("k" & iRow).Value = "Total"
    Range("l" & iRow).Font.Bold = True
    Range("l" & iRow).Formula = "=sum(l" & CStr(fRow) & ":l" & CStr(iRow) & ")"
    iRow = iRow + 1
    fRow = iRow
 Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
 End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
'
End Sub
```

[Picture of Sheet and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO9M4.png)

Comment: Hi, im getting the impression from the line `Range("l" & iRow).Formula = "=sum(l" & CStr(fRow) & ":l" & CStr(iRow) & ")"` theyre trying to Sum themselves, are you sure they are the correct rows and columns to be summing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are a creating a circular reference here `"=sum(l" & CStr(fRow) & ":l" & CStr(iRow) & ")"`

`Sum` formula cell is inclucing itself in the sum range.

Change this to

`"=sum(l" & CStr(fRow) & ":l" & CStr(iRow-1`) `& ")"`, should work.

Comment: So it worked but I had to change the iRow- to iRow-1

Comment: Good practice if a formula is not working is to stick it into a msgbox and you usually see the problem right away!